# How to make function output the key for a password function

Tags: javascript, variables, passwords, key, var

I am trying to create a page with uses the amount of days it has been since a certain date as a password. The only password that works is static and surrounded by "". I want to be able to use the result of my days since function as the password. How do I do this?

On the line which says "`if (pass1 == "abcde") {`" I tried changing "`abcde`" to  the name of my function for daysSince as well as the final var I got from that function.

```
function passWord() {
    var testV = 1;
    var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password to see deez burgerz','Password ');

    while (testV < 3) {
        if (!pass1) 
            history.go(-1);
        if (pass1 == "abcde") {
            alert('Lucky guess...');
            window.open('http://bowenpowell.com');
            break;
        } 
        testV+=1;
        var pass1 = 
            prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, ur dumb.','Password');
    }
    if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3) 
        history.go(-1);
    return " ";
}
```

My function for days since:

```
function dateFunction() {
    var currentDate = new Date(),
      m = currentDate.getMonth() +1,
      d = currentDate.getDate(),
      y = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var current = y + "/" + m + "/" + d;
    var date2 = '2018/9/4';
current = current.split('/');
date2 = date2.split('/');
current = new Date(current[0], current[1], current[2]);
date2 = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);
current_unixtime = parseInt(current.getTime() / 1000);
date2_unixtime = parseInt(date2.getTime() / 1000);
var timeDifference = current_unixtime - date2_unixtime;
var timeDifferenceInHours = timeDifference / 60 / 60;
var timeDifferenceInDays = timeDifferenceInHours  / 24 + 2;


    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timeDifferenceInDays;
}
```

I've tried

```
if (pass1 == timeDifferenceInDays) {
if (pass1 == dateFunction()) {
if pass1 == timeDifferenceInDays {
if pass1 == dateFunction() {
if pass1 == 'timeDifferenceInDays' {
if pass1 == 'dateFunction()' {
```

Comment: For one, you're missing a `&` in your final `if` statement, should be `&&`.

Comment: Show the code that you tried but didn't work, so we can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Did you put `()` after the name of the function when you replaced `"abcde"` with it? You need to do that to call the function.

Comment: @Barmar I've updated the code with what I've tried

Comment: `dateFunction()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you kinda sir you go in my good boy book

Answer (score 0):

`dateDifference()` needs to return the value that you want to use as the password.

```js
function dateFunction() {
  var currentDate = new Date(),
    m = currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
    d = currentDate.getDate(),
    y = currentDate.getFullYear();
  var current = y + "/" + m + "/" + d;
  var date2 = '2018/9/4';
  current = current.split('/');
  date2 = date2.split('/');
  current = new Date(current[0], current[1], current[2]);
  date2 = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);
  current_unixtime = parseInt(current.getTime() / 1000);
  date2_unixtime = parseInt(date2.getTime() / 1000);
  var timeDifference = current_unixtime - date2_unixtime;
  var timeDifferenceInHours = timeDifference / 60 / 60;
  var timeDifferenceInDays = timeDifferenceInHours / 24 + 2;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timeDifferenceInDays;
  return timeDifferenceInDays.toString();
}
```

Then you can use:

```
if (pass1 == dateFunction())
```